# I want to remove double quotes inside a JSON string through regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON something like this

```
{
      "DocumentID": 28663,
      "DocumentName": " Have a "HAPPY" and safe journey ",
}
```

I am getting error

> Unexpected token H in JSON at position 315784

So I have to remove double quotes surrounding `HAPPY`.

How do I do this?

Comment: That's an invalid JSON object. You will need the check the source of that content to fix it before it's generated. Can you clarify how this JSON is being generated?

Comment: I got that JSON after serializing

Comment: Where do you generate this?

Comment: if I remove double quotes surrounding Happy then it will be a valid JSON. I checked it in JSON formatter

Comment: @Armin Actually I will be getting a data inside a table. By using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); inside c# code behind

Comment: You will need to fix this server side. Regexps are unnecessary if you pass your object through a proper JSON encoder. Please see the answer below for more details, also the comment from Jonathan Schmold.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C# to encode. From the MSDN website:

> Json.NET should be used serialization and deserialization. Provides
>   serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled
>   applications.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Using that library should guarantee you getting a valid JSON string instead of an invalid JavaScript serialization.

Comment: If using ASP.Net, he can even just use return Json(Object)

Answer (score 1):

`" Have a "HAPPY" and safe journey "` is not a correct string, you should write something like this:

`" Have a 'HAPPY' and safe journey "` or `' Have a "HAPPY" and safe journey '`

Comment: But I got this kind of JSON after parsing.

Comment: @Revathi that sound's impossible, if its like that the problem is on server response

Comment: By using Regualr expression, I guess its possible right?

Comment: By checking if there are any characters before and after double quotes. if the regular expression satisfies this condition, den we can remove those double quotes by using replace function

Comment: @Revathi how can you replace that from a variable that isn't a string?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can solve this without reg ex. Most probably you're parsing the JSON wrong way.
But still anyway here's the code to replace double quote with single in json string

```
function passJSON_ItWillReplaceDoubleQuoteWithSingle(str){
  var firstDoubleQuoteFound = false;
  var escapeNextDouble = false;
  var newStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    var s = str.charAt(i);
    if(s == '"' && !firstDoubleQuoteFound){
        firstDoubleQuoteFound = true;
        newStr += '"';
    } else if(s == '"' && firstDoubleQuoteFound && !escapeNextDouble){
        if( isNextNonSpaceAcceptable(str, i+1) ){
            newStr += s;
            firstDoubleQuoteFound = false;
        } else {
            escapeNextDouble = true;
            newStr += '\'';
        }
    } else if(s == '"' && firstDoubleQuoteFound && escapeNextDouble){
        newStr += '\'';
        escapeNextDouble = false;
    } else{
        newStr += s;
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}
function doubleQuoteReplaced(str){
    return str.replace(/"/g, "'");
}
function isNextNonSpaceAcceptable(str, i){
    for(var j=i ; j<str.length ; j++){
        var s = str.charAt(j);
        if( s==' ' || s=='\t')
            continue;
        if( s == '}' || s==',' || s == ':')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

and here's how I checked

```
var str = "{\"some_key\" : \"some \"Happy\" people\", \"next_key\":\"Z\"}";
console.log(passJSON_ItWillReplaceDoubleQuoteWithSingle(str));
```

It will fail when there's comma or '}' or ':' just after double quote